# When would you use NSNumber literal to create encapsulated character values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

I'm just going through Apple's iOS development tutorial at the moment and reading the chapter on the Foundation framework and value objects.

Just on the NSNumber class, it says:

> You can even use NSNumber literals to create encapsulated Boolean and
>   character values.
>
> NSNumber *myBoolValue = @YES; NSNumber *myCharValue = @'V';

I'm just wondering, when, or why, or in what scenario, might you want to use NSNumber for a character value rather than using NSString, say?

Comment: Why not?  Just because it's possible doesn't mean you have to use it, but there may be some odd scenarios where it's useful.  (And `@YES` is definitely useful, for setting boolean values in JSON.)

Comment: I'm interested in knowing what those odd scenarios might be. Thanks re your point on JSON.

Comment: I don't know when one might want an NSNumber with the literal value for Unicode `V`, but if someone did want it, it would be there.  I could invent a situation where, eg, an NSArray was used to hold the characters of a string, but I don't know what might require that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSNumber is useful for encapsulating primitive values to be inserted into Objective-C collection classes such as NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary, etc.

Image a scenario where you would want to iterate over each character in an ASCII string and extract a unique set of vowels used. You can evaluate each character and add it to an NSMutableSet. To do so, you would need to encapsulate each character in an NSNumber as NSMutableSet expects an Objective-C object. This is just one example, but the concept applies to many situations where primitives need to be added into a collection.

Comment: Yeah, the hard part is to think of a scenario where a *literal* NSNumber char value is required.  Your hash set of vowels case might be such a scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one case is where you're using KVC to set a value for a key, and the property type is `char`:

```
[object setValue:@'a' forKey:someCharPropertyName];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSNumber with characters to return its ASCII Code, so V would return 86.

I don't think many people use it that much, but you could probably use it for character validation. I think it just one of those things where Apple went, yeah, lets put that in for the heck of it.

It's really not used for much else. The @YES and @NO is the same as YES and NO, so its kinda inelegant in some places.

Comment: Proto, what do you mean by 'character validation'? Also do you mean that you don't need to use a literal or use the @ sign when using boolean values?

Comment: Neither of those are true statements. @ 'V', @ YES, and @ NO provide instances of NSNumber, which are not equal to their primitive counterparts. (Spaces added since the StackExchange app thinks I'm trying to mention someone..) To demonstrate this, try adding NO to an array. It won't work, because NO is seen similarly to nil, and you can't add a nil object to an array. Adding @ NO will work perfectly fine, however. Also, to get the ASCII value of a letter, it would make more sense to simply cast it using (int)charName rather than calling [@ 'V' intValue];

Comment: Why does @NO work there? Because it is directly declared as an obj-c object?